# Xamarin ContentObserver

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

trying to get a content observer to work in Xamarin Android.

It's not currently being executed when an event happens.
I tried converting from a java example and fixed it up for c#

I know there is not code to implement the event mod yet, trying to see it get caught first then will add the code.
This is the observer:

```
using System;
using Android.Database;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Content;

namespace FileTest
{
public class MyObserver : ContentObserver 
{

    private readonly Android.Net.Uri _uri;

    public MyObserver(Android.Net.Uri uri): base(null)
    {
        _uri = uri;
    }


    public override void OnChange(bool selfChange) {
        this.OnChange (selfChange, null);
        Console.WriteLine ("change that I caught  " );
    }


//      public override void OnChange(bool selfChange, Uri uri) {
    //
    //  Console.WriteLine ("change that I caught   " );
    //
    //}
}
}
```

this is the call:

```
ContentObserver   observer = new MyObserver(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("content://com.Test/databases/Data.db"));
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        var a = Android.Net.Uri.Parse  ("content://com.Test/databases/Data.db");
        ContentResolver.RegisterContentObserver(a, false, observer);
```

Comment: what do you want to observe?

Comment: data in a db being inserted/deleted/etc

Comment: see documentation of `ContentResolver#notifyChange` to find out how to notifify registered observers

Comment: *what do you want to observe?*  *data in a db being inserted/deleted/etc* ... hahaha it is not done automagically ....  `Uri.Parse  ("/data/data/com.Test/databases/Data.db")` ???? `"/data/data/com.Test/databases/Data.db"` is not an Uri

Comment: so how do I make that a uri please

Comment: what am i missing, hence the asking for help